Kotlin: How to replace .not() by '!'?
I have two nullable ancapsulated objects like:
class NullableObject(
    val a : AnotherNullable? = null
    val b : String = "b"
}

class AnotherNullable(val id: String) {
    val hash: Integer? = someHashFunction(id)
    val hashInvalidHash: Boolean = (hash == null)

}

where I use the not() operator like:
val hasAnotherNullableHash = nullableObject?.anotherNullableObject?.hasInvalidHash.not() ?: false

I read the hasInvalidHash property or set a default false if either nullableObject or anotherNullableObject were null ..
Question:
How to I transform this .not() operator to the unary ! ?
val hasAnotherNullableHash = !nullableObject?.anotherNullableObject?.hasInvalidHash!!

I have to !! and the default value false is also not possible..

calling a class 'Nullable' is confusing - nullability is a property of fields/parameters/variables, not a property of the class

Assuming you have a structure like this (I fixed a few typos in your code):
class NullableObject(
    val anotherNullableObject : AnotherNullable? = null
)

class AnotherNullable(val id: String) {
    val hash: Int? = someHashFunction(id)
    val hasInvalidHash: Boolean = hash == null
}

To use ! here, replace the !! in your attempt with a ?:, and apply ! to the whole x ?: y expression. Because of this, the RHS of ?: should be true - it will get turned into false by the ! that is applied to the whole expression.
!(nullableObject?.anotherNullableObject?.hasInvalidHash ?: true)

That said, when working with Bool?s, it is often more readable to use == true or == false instead. In this case,
nullableObject?.anotherNullableObject?.hasInvalidHash == false

